# Is there a well-defined notion of size where the set of rationals is “bigger” than the set of integers?

Tags: measure-theory

I want to rephrase my question: is there a definition of size that retains order for strict subsets but still allows you to compare or equate sets that are mutually exclusive from each other/contain mutually exclusive elements? The main examples I would like this definition to satisfy are:

The set of positive integers is equivalent to the set of negative integers.

Natural numbers < integers < rationals < reals

Even positive integers = odd positive integers

My original question:
The main ways to quantify “size” of a set that I’ve come across is cardinality and measure, both of which equate rationals to integers (bijection/measure 0). Is there any other metric for evaluating size of a set that, for instance, preserves order for sets that are strictly subsets of other sets? For instance, some metric that denotes the size of evens equal to the size of odds but denotes both as less than the size of all integers.

Comment: The rationals are dense in themselves (between any two rationals there is at least one rational), and even more, they are dense in the reals (between any two reals there is at least one rational). The integers are not even dense in themselves.

Comment: In the context of containment $\mathbb{Q}$ is larger than $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There is "box dimension" (a.k.a. Minkowski dimension, Bouligand dimension, and other names).  Integers have dimension $0$; rationals have dimension $1$.  Also try "natural density".

Comment: Oops! Let's try this again. (Error realized as I was thinking about this when I was brushing my teeth a few moments ago.) The rationals are dense in themselves (every neighborhood of a rational contains at least at least two rationals), and even more, they are dense in the reals (every neighborhood of a real contains at least two rationals). The Cantor set is an example of a set that is dense in itself that is not dense in the reals. (I would need to double check on this to be sure, but it seems that the notion of "dense in itself" doesn't work for the standard order notion of density.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, yes, Cantor-type sets have no isolated points...

Comment: If there is no shared parent set, then the rational numbers and the integers have exactly the same size (cardinality). So any notion to distinguish them must refer to how they are situated in some common mathematical environment.